# Shell script to test URL for HTTP response codes & take action

Tags: bash, shell, http, tomcat

I have an issue with a bash shell script I have written to test a parameterized URL and return the HTTP response code.

1. The script takes a URL as a parameter.
2. This script is sourced by another script, some values are provided by the source-r
3. The script works, but not as designed

My intent was to pass a URL to this script, validate the URL is well formed for our internal needs, then attempt to test the URL and retrieve an HTTP response code.

The script should retry a configured number of times (5) with a pause between attempts (30sec), but it does not do this.

My hope was that a test of the URL would be instant and I would need to sleep to give an application (let's say in Tomcat or JBoss) a chance to start.

Instead what I get is a very long pause while the application is starting and is in a sort of *limbo*. Once the application comes online, or fails to start the validation attempt returns the proper HTTP code as designed and the script returns activity to the source-r.

```
#!/bin/bash
#######################################################################################################
# APPLICATION ENDPOINT VALIDATION
#
# This function tests a parameterized URI using cURL and uses the HTTP response value to determine the
# whether the targeted endpoint is available.
#
# Endpoint validation returns a binary value to indicate whether the response was satisfactory.
#
# This functionality is generally used after an application is deployed or restarted.
#######################################################################################################
# TEST THE ENDPOINT
#######################################################################################################
function testEndpointAvailability {
    # -L is used to ensure cURL follows up to 30 status changes through to the end.
    # Without the -L, cURL will stop at the Apache reverse-proxy 301 status instead of listening for 
    # the eventual response.
    endpointResponse=$(curl -oL --write-out '%{http_code}\n' --silent --head "${endpointToValidate}")

    if ! [[ -z "${endpointResponse}" ]]
    then
        if ! [[ "${endpointResponse}" -eq "200" ]]
        then
            logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "HTTP Response was: ${endpointResponse}" "INFO"
        else
            logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "HTTP Response was OK: ${endpointResponse}" "INFO"
        fi
    fi
}
#######################################################################################################
# LOOP VALIDATION ATTEMPTS
#######################################################################################################
function validationLoop {
    if [[ -z "${endpointResponse}" ]]
    then
        testEndpointAvailability
    fi

    while [[ "${endpointResponse}" -ne "200" ]] || [[ "${retryCount}" -gt "0" ]]
    do
        if ! [[ "${retryCount}" -eq "0" ]] && [[ "${retryCount}" -ne "${originalRetryCount}" ]]
        then

            testEndpointAvailability
            sleep "${retryDelay}"
            retryCount=$(( "${retryCount}" - 1 ))
        else
            logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "HTTP Response was OK: ${endpointResponse}" "INFO"
            return 0
        fi
    done
}
#######################################################################################################
# VALIDATE ENDPOINT AVAILABILITY
#
# validateEndpointAvailability endpointToValidate
#######################################################################################################
function validateEndpointAvailability {
    ###################################################################################################
    # TODO
    #
    # [ ] Externalize instantiation of retryCount and retryDelay to properties file(s).
    # [ ] Externalize regex to property file(s).
    ###################################################################################################
    retryCount="5"
    originalRetryCount="${retryCount}"
    retryDelay="30"

    endpointToValidate="$1"

    ###################################################################################################
    # Regex determines viable URL patterns, does not account for all spec options, but meets this
    # script's needs for testing the internal URLs for in-house applications.
    ###################################################################################################
    regex='(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]'

    # Determine if properly parameter count was used
    if ! [[ "$#" -eq "1" ]]
    then
        logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "Unable to validate endpoint availability: Improper parameter count." "ERROR"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Check parameterized endpoint for valid structure
    if echo "${endpointToValidate}" | grep -Eq "${regex}"
    then 
        logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "Endpoint appears to be properly formed, proceeding with availability check." "INFO"

        validationLoop
    else
        logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfAdminLogFile}" "Unable to validate endpoint availability: Provided endpoint is improperly formed." "ERROR"
        exit 1
    fi
}
trap cleanupOnExit exit
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your curl command -o takes a filename argument to write into, so I think curl will try to write to a file called 'L' in the current directory, thus ignoring it as a directive.  You might also like to add a connect timeout (if it is indeed Tomcat that you are awaiting for) '--connect-timeout <seconds>'

Comment: I understood the `-o` to replace `--write-out`, if that is incorrect I will need to replace it with `--write-out` instead.

I hadn't considered the `--connect-timeout` option and admit to a failure to RTFM on curl's more esoteric options.

These are good suggestions and I will play with them a bit today.

Comment: @Cwissy Thanks for the input. It does seem that cURL will now wait a limited amount of time for both connection and for HTTP response.

This does not, however, resolve my issue with trying to validate the URL multiple times during a period to determine if the application actually comes up or not.

Here is my updated cURL string:

`endpointResponse=$(curl -L --write-out '%{http_code}\n' --silent --head --max-time 30 --connect-timeout 0 "${endpointToValidate}")`